# Put external data into Drupal CCK data to be themed

Tags: php, drupal, view, drupal-modules, cck

I am using Drupal. I have used hook_menu to grab data into Drupal from an outside web service.

I love using CCK, Contemplate, and Views; I would like to be able to theme the data coming into Drupal using Contemplate or Views or the CCK system.

Is there a way to either:

- Merge the data into the PHP $node or
  $content array? Would this be smart?
- Assign the data coming in to the CCK 
  fields setup (that match the
  fieldnames from the data array coming
  from the web service).

I don't want the data to be stored in the local Drupal database.

Either one of these solutions would work (if possible), or is there another solution to using the Views and CCK and contemplate modules with outside data sources? (I already have a module that grabs the data).

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have to bite the bullet here. Views is incredibly powerful, and this I feel is always the optimal solution due to it's flexibility, but at it's core Views is a visual SQL creator - i.e. you need to have information in the database before Views will see it.

My suggestion would be to:

1. Import the external feeds into the {node} database using a custom CCK node type that describes the schema of the external feeds (you say you already have a custom module that can read the feeds already)
2. Use Views to mash up the data into whatever you can think of